# Vim: Different maps in different visual modes

Tags: vi, vim

I'm using the common trick to let j and k work better with wrapped lines in normal mode by adding this to my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent> j gj
nnoremap <silent> k gk
```

I just thought of using this in visual mode as well by doing this:

```
vnoremap <silent> j gj
vnoremap <silent> k gk
```

It works great in normal visual mode, but it sucks in visual line mode (Shift+V) or visual block mode. Since I want to move the actual line in those modes, not up and down in the same line.

How can I us this map only in normal visual mode?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to let `gj`  work with `V (line-wise visual)` mode.

Assume that it could work, then when you do `gj` on very long (wrapped) line, vim will select a part of a line, that is to say, it is not line-wise visual mode any longer.

The smallest selected unit  in line-wise selection should be a line.

### update

Well I have to clarify, if you selected a long line with `V`, **within the selected area**, `gj` works, it moves your cursor up/down.  But if you want to let `gj` additionally select a "on-screen line" down, it won't work, `gj` here does same as `j`

### update2

a workaround (only with `j/gj` as example) for OP's comment:

```
nnoremap V :vnoremap j j<cr>V
nnoremap v :vnoremap j gj<cr>v
```

or (Peter Rincker's suggestion)

```
xnoremap <expr> j mode() ==# 'V' ? 'j' : 'gj'
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to keep the normal j and k behaviour for line-wise visual. And only want to remap it to the g variant in `v` (normal visual) mode.

Comment: Thanks @Kent, that was the push in the right direction that I needed.

Comment: Expression mapping might be easier: `xnoremap <expr> j mode() ==# 'V' ? 'j' : 'gj'`.

Comment: @PeterRincker yes, with `<expr>` is better! thx, I would add in answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kent his answer I figured out a way to make this work the way I wanted.

```
nnoremap <silent> V :silent! vunmap j<cr>:silent! vunmap k<cr>V
nnoremap <silent> v :vnoremap j gj<cr>:vnoremap k gk<cr>v
vnoremap <silent> V <esc>:silent! vunmap j<cr>:silent! vunmap k<cr>gvV
vnoremap <silent> v <esc>:vnoremap j gj<cr>:vnoremap k gk<cr>gvv
```

I do however think that its a bit of an ugly hack since it unmaps and maps the keys everytime `v` or `V` is pressed.